# How to prefer one IPv6 link over another?

Tags: debian, routing, ipv6

I have a server with Debian Buster and 2 network cards, with 1GbE and 10GbE respectively. Both cards are configured with

```
iface enpXs0 inet6 auto
    privext 2
```

Both cards receive a global IPv6 address and `ip -6 route` shows routes to the local net and a default route for both devices.

For outgoing connections I want to prefer the 10GbE link over the 1GbE link, of course. **How to make one IPv6 link be preferred over another?**

`/etc/network/interfaces` doesn't offer a `metric` setting for IPv6 according to `man interfaces`. I also had no effect when I tried it.

The often recommend tool `ifmetric` is documented to handle only IPv4.

I tried to set the `metric` parameter of the created routes but this doesn't work because …

1. I fail to write a `ip -6 route replace ...` call to actually modify the existing route instead of insert new routes
2. My created routes have no TTL while the autocreated routes have a TTL and will be replaced with the original `metric` value, I think. I think this might because of privacy extensions.

Is the `metric` paramter the right setting at all? How to configure this on the interface to apply it to all its routes?

Comment: Yes, use metrics. Try the `ip` command to add the metric https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/413036/186861 (`ip -6 route add default dev enpXs0 metric 1`) would seem to be what you want or similar.

Comment: Wrong: Use the keyword `priority` in ip rule command. :-)

Comment: `man ip` does not show a priority command under debian/ubuntu. "ip rule"?

Comment: Meant to add - if you look at link he accomplishes it by using the post-up to execute the `ip` command inside `/etc/network/interfaces` (works across reboots) ref: https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch05.en.html#_scripting_with_the_ifupdown_system